# Update rows with value from same table when LEFT JOIN can return multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a value in table with another value from same table. I tried doing it with LEFT JOIN:

```
UPDATE
    acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag
SET
    Verkettungsartikel = ISNULL(unt2.Unt_ID, Verkettungsartikel)
FROM
    acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT unt2.Unt_ID, Unt_Prod_ID FROM acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag unt2
        WHERE Unt_ID IS NOT NULL
    ) unt2 ON Verkettungsartikel = unt2.Unt_Prod_ID
WHERE Verkettungsartikel IS NOT NULL
```

As you can see, I join the same table in LEFT JOIN on Unt_Prod_ID value. However, multiple rows from the table can have the same Unt_Prod_ID value and I just need to get the top row in LEFT JOIN.

This query works when LEFT JOIN returns one row, but there will be cases where it can return multiple rows.

I tried using OUTER APPLY:

```
UPDATE
    acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag
SET
    Verkettungsartikel = ISNULL(unt2.Unt_ID, Verkettungsartikel)
FROM
    acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 unt2.Unt_ID, Unt_Prod_ID FROM acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag unt2
        WHERE Unt_ID IS NOT NULL
        AND Verkettungsartikel = unt2.Unt_Prod_ID
    ) unt2
WHERE Verkettungsartikel IS NOT NULL
```

But it doesn't change the value - the old value remains.

How could I modify this query so that I only get the top value when multiple rows in t_Unterlag table have the same Unt_Prod_ID value?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect results?

Comment: You *really* need to get into the habit of aliasing all your objects in the `FROM` and  qualifying **all** your columns. Especially when the 2 objects are the *same* object. Youe `OUTER APPLY` isn't correlated due to your lack of qualifying. `Unt_ID IS NOT NULL AND Verkettungsartikel = unt2.Unt_Prod_ID` is actually be parsed as `unt2.Unt_ID IS NOT NULL AND unt2.Verkettungsartikel = unt2.Unt_Prod_ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CROSS APPLY and aliasing (unt1, unt2...)

```
UPDATE unt1
   SET unt1.Verkettungsartikel = unt2.Unt_ID 
  FROM acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag unt1
 CROSS
 APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP 1 
              unt2.Unt_ID
         FROM acc_sem_unt.t_Unterlag unt2
        WHERE unt2.Unt_ID is not null
          and unt2.Unt_Prod_ID = unt1.Verkettungsartikel
      ) unt2
  WHERE unt1.Verkettungsartikel is not null
```